# VB.NET code MS Acess as database and getting error in my code after successful compilation. SYNTAX ERROR in INSERT INTO command

Tags: vb.net

I am getting error in INSERT INTO command.

Code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Public Class newemployee

    Dim read As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Public da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim str As String
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public ds1 As New DataSet
    Public ds2 As New DataSet

    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim er, pho As Integer
    Dim Photos1() As Byte

    Private Sub newemployee_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        read = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source="
        datafile = "C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\HRIS SYSTEM\loginformdatabase\BLUESTREAM.accdb"
        connstring = read & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        ds.Clear()
        pho = 0
        DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now

        If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            myconnection.Close()
        End If

        myconnection.Open()
        er = 0
        'cn.Open()
        str = "select * from bsemployee"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "bsemployee")

    End Sub

    'INSERT
    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ds.Clear()
        str = "select * from bsemployee"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "bsemployee")
        Dim SLNO As Integer
        Dim ph As String
        SLNO = ds.Tables("bsemployee").Rows.Count + 1
        If SLNO >= 0 Then
            ph = SLNO
        Else
            ph = 0
        End If
        If er = 0 Then
            Try
                cmd.Connection = myconnection
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bsemployee(SL NO,EMP SSN,PID,BSPS EMP ID,SIIM ID,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,NAME,FATHER/HUSBAND NAME,DEPARTMENT,GENDER,DOB,AGE,CURRENT ADDRESS,PERMANENT ADDRESS,EMAIL,COUNTRY,STATE,PHONE NUMBER,PAN,ADHAR NUMER,TE DOJ,
BSPS DOJ,DIVISION,DESIGNATION,TE EMAIL,BSPS EMAIL,BSPS DESIGNATION,COST CENTER,SALARY GRADE,SHIFT,BANK ACCOUNT NO,ACCOUNT CODE,BSPS PF NO,1ST LEVEL SUPERVISOR,2ND LEVEL SUPERVISOR,MANGER,OFFER LETTER ISSUE DATE,NOTICE PERIOD,BOND SIGN,NO OF YEARS,REPORTING,
BG VERIFICATION STATUS,DATE OF RESIGNATION,BASIC SALARY,HOUSE RENT ALLOWANCE,PROVIDENT FUND(Employer distribution),LEAVE TRAVEL ALLOWANCE,MEDICAL ALLOWANCE,SPECIAL ALLOWANCE,STAT BONUS,ESI,MONTHLY GAURENTED CASH,ANNUAL BASIC SALARY,ANNUAL HOUSE RENT ALLOWANCE,
ANNUAL PROVIDENT FUND,ANNUAL LEAVE TRAVEL ALLOWANCE,ANNUAL MEDICAL ALLOWANCE,ANNUAL SPECIAL ALLOWANCE,ANNUAL STAT ALLOWANCE,ANNUAL ESI,ANNUAL GARUNTEED CASH,FOOD COUPON PER ANNUM,GRATIUTY PER ANNUM,INSURANCE PREMIUM PER ANNUM,ANNUAL BONUS,TOTAL COST BENIFIT,GROSS COMPENSATION)
VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "''" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "',
'" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox13.Text & "','" & TextBox14.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "','" & TextBox16.Text & "','" & TextBox17.Text & "','" & TextBox18.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker3.Text & "','" & TextBox20.Text & "',
'" & TextBox21.Text & "','" & TextBox22.Text & "','" & TextBox23.Text & "','" & TextBox24.Text & "','" & ComboBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox26.Text & "','" & TextBox26.Text & "','" & ComboBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox25.Text & "','" & TextBox27.Text & "','" & ComboBox13.Text & "','" & ComboBox5.Text & "','" & ComboBox6.Text & "','" & ComboBox7.Text & "',
'" & DateTimePicker4.Text & "','" & ComboBox8.Text & "','" & ComboBox9.Text & "','" & ComboBox10.Text & "','" & ComboBox11.Text & "','" & ComboBox12.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker5.Text & "','" & TextBox28.Text & "','" & TextBox29.Text & "','" & TextBox30.Text & "','" & TextBox31.Text & "','" & TextBox32.Text & "','" & TextBox33.Text & "',
'" & TextBox34.Text & "','" & TextBox35.Text & "','" & TextBox36.Text & "','" & TextBox37.Text & "','" & TextBox38.Text & "','" & TextBox39.Text & "','" & TextBox40.Text & "','" & TextBox41.Text & "','" & TextBox42.Text & "','" & TextBox43.Text & "','" & TextBox44.Text & "','" & TextBox45.Text & "','" & TextBox46.Text & "','" & TextBox47.Text & "',
'" & TextBox48.Text & "','" & TextBox49.Text & "','" & TextBox50.Text & "','" & TextBox51.Text & "')"

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'if command is executed'
                If pho = 1 Then
                    'Photo Saving
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand
                    cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Photos VALUE (@PhID, @EID, @EName, @EMPImage) "
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhID", ph)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", TextBox1.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EName", TextBox8.Text)
                    Photos1 = File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPImage", Photos1)
                    cmd.Connection = myconnection
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                'MsgBox("New Class Added.")
                Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("New Employee Added. Want To Add Another One.", "Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If result = DialogResult.No Then
                    Me.Close()
                ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    ds.Clear()
                    TextBox1.Clear()
                    TextBox2.Clear()
                    TextBox3.Clear()
                    TextBox4.Clear()
                    TextBox5.Clear()
                    TextBox6.Clear()
                    TextBox7.Clear()
                    TextBox8.Clear()
                    TextBox9.Clear()
                    TextBox10.Clear()
                    TextBox11.Clear()
                    TextBox12.Clear()
                    TextBox13.Clear()
                    TextBox14.Clear()
                    TextBox15.Clear()
                    TextBox16.Clear()
                    TextBox17.Clear()
                    TextBox18.Clear()
                    TextBox20.Clear()
                    TextBox21.Clear()
                    TextBox22.Clear()
                    TextBox23.Clear()
                    TextBox24.Clear()
                    TextBox25.Clear()
                    TextBox26.Clear()
                    TextBox27.Clear()
                    TextBox28.Clear()
                    TextBox29.Clear()
                    TextBox30.Clear()
                    TextBox31.Clear()
                    TextBox32.Clear()
                    TextBox33.Clear()
                    TextBox34.Clear()
                    TextBox35.Clear()
                    TextBox36.Clear()
                    TextBox37.Clear()
                    TextBox38.Clear()
                    TextBox39.Clear()
                    TextBox40.Clear()
                    TextBox41.Clear()
                    TextBox42.Clear()
                    TextBox43.Clear()
                    TextBox44.Clear()
                    TextBox45.Clear()
                    TextBox46.Clear()
                    TextBox47.Clear()
                    TextBox48.Clear()
                    TextBox49.Clear()
                    TextBox50.Clear()
                    TextBox51.Clear()
                    ComboBox1.ResetText()
                    ComboBox2.ResetText()
                    ComboBox3.ResetText()
                    ComboBox4.ResetText()
                    ComboBox5.ResetText()
                    ComboBox6.ResetText()
                    ComboBox7.ResetText()
                    ComboBox8.ResetText()
                    ComboBox9.ResetText()
                    ComboBox9.ResetText()
                    ComboBox10.ResetText()
                    ComboBox11.ResetText()
                    ComboBox12.ResetText()
                    ComboBox13.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker1.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker2.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker3.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker4.ResetText()
                    DateTimePicker5.ResetText()
                    str = "select * from bsemployee"
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(ds, "bsemployee")
                    SLNO = ds.Tables("bsemployee").Rows.Count + 1
                    If SLNO >= 0 Then
                        TextBox1.Text = SLNO
                    Else
                        TextBox1.Text = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'insert close
        End If
        'myconnection close
    End Sub
```

Comment: please show the error message you got. Probably you found the error yourself.

Comment: Hi Deepika, Welcome to Stack Overflow!Couple of comments. Compiled code deosnt mean that it works as intended. You are running into an issue with a SQL command that your application has created.
Try not to do everything in one procedure, try splitting it out ie run a sql sttment to get the SLNO, then run another to Insert the employee data, then maybe another to the photos, then a final procedure to clear all your textboxs etc. This will make it easier to debug and see where errors are occuring. Lastly, are all your fields in `bsemployee` text or are any numeric?

Comment: Field Names with spaces must be wrapped inside [ ] square brackets. Also, you really need to look into using Parameters instead of concatenating values from user input. This is very susceptible to SQL Injection. I mean, you show that you understand how they are used, why not stick with the proper way of building statements?

Comment: I hope this is a single user application. It appears you are incrementing an ID in code. This will fail in a multi-user environment. Why not let Access handle the auto-numbering?

Comment: It looks like every field is entered as text/string/varchar . Some of these fields should be something other than a text type. If they are not the data will be troublesome to use. Please use Parameters.Add (NOT .AddWithValue) which includes the OleDbType so you can immediately see if your parameter .Value is of the correct type.

Comment: `GAURENTED` misspelling in code or in database?

Answer (score -2):

The first place I'd look would be for any text with an apostrophe in it - e.g. a surname like O'Rourke - that'll mess up your commandtext. Also, are the date formats compatible with the database date formats - i.e. UK format dates like 25/02/2019 aren't well like by US-centric databases. Similar situation with any numeric formats - might there be currency symbols in the text box?

Comment: Good thought about O'Rourke. This could be solved by using Parameters.